# Wrap two divs with different class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've these divs

```
<div class="col_1_6"></div>
<div class="col_1_4"></div>

<div class="col_1_6"></div>
<div class="col_1_4"></div>

<div class="col_1_4"></div>
<div class="col_1_6"></div>
```

I want whatever the order of the divs, wrap **col_1_4** and **col_1_6** in a div called **row_content**

```
<div class="row_content">
   <div class="col_1_6"></div>
   <div class="col_1_4"></div>
</div>
<div class="row_content">
   <div class="col_1_4"></div>
   <div class="col_1_6"></div>
</div>
```

I already try this :

```
$('.col_1_6, .col_1_4').wrapAll('<div class="row"></div>')
```

But it wrap all the divs not each two divs.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible, without some form of logic to specify where to find the next div to wrap together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select all your `divs` and then do a `for` loop that increment by 2 every iteration.

With the index of the loop, you can then use `.slice` on the jQuery element and that wrap your `divs`.

```js
var $divs = $('.col_1_6, .col_1_4');

for(var i = 0; i < $divs.length; i+=2){
    $divs.slice(i, i+2).wrapAll('<div class="row"></div>');
    console.log($divs);
}
```

```css
.row{
  background: red;
  margin : 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col_1_6">1</div>
<div class="col_1_4">2</div>

<div class="col_1_6">3</div>
<div class="col_1_4">4</div>

<div class="col_1_4">5</div>
<div class="col_1_6">6</div>
```

Comment: Yes exactly what I need, I understand your loop now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've found this method which works

```
$(".col_1_6").each(function(index) {
    $(this).next(".col_1_4").andSelf().wrapAll("<div class='row' />")
});
```

but this only work if all div are in this order .col_1_6 > .col_1_4 and not .col_1_4 > col_1_6 as in your html

http://jsfiddle.net/mrjx9dav/11/

Answer (score 0):

Another not-so-pretty solution that wraps every 2 divs that has the class starting with `col_1`.

```
$('div[class^="col_1"]').each(function(ind) {    
    ind%2 === 0 && ($(this).add($(this).next()).wrapAll('<div class="row"></div>'));
});
```

**[-Demo-](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/f1z43L1x/2/)**